Angular does not load images from Assets
I'm making an angular application, and inside the assets I created a folder called "image", and I placed my images there, and then I reference them in the html component, but after using ng and checking the application, the image does not appear, giving an error not found in the console, the server does not recognize the image page created within assets


and the strangest thing is that if I place the image directly in the assets it recognizes it

Why is this happening ? how to solve ? How to make Angular recognize the folders inside assets?
I try to change folder and move images

Please do not post code as image. See here

I put image of the code to show the folder structure

Then, please post your code. Without that, we can not figure out why you are facing the issue.

those filenames look alot like they've got spaces in them. start by removing the spaces in the file names, but your question is crazy unclear.

See the Andrew's answer. Angular copy your folder assets in the same directory where the index.html is (that it's where the bundles.js are). Think also that an Angular app don't take account your folder structure (imagine if not, what happens if you change this folder structure)

Always important to remember angular goes through a build step and you're not referencing an asset within your project structure but what will be the public assets folder when served via a server. Easiest way to see this is look in your dist/ folder after running a build.
The default, determined by your angular.json, is that assets gets copied out as you've put it in assets, so src will look like src="./assets/...

( In Portuguese )
Brother, pelo seu HTML eu vou responder tú em brazuca, cara isso daí acontece/pode acontecer por diversas razões, eu vou colocar algumas aqui:
1 - Angular encucou com a segurança, o angular é uma framework bem regrada na parte de segurança, e normalmente pra ele acessar imagens, elas precisam vir diretamente da pasta assets e alguma derivação conhecida como img/imgs/images existe uma possibilidade mínima, MÍNIMA mesmo do angular estar de chatisse com o nome da subpasta na assets chamada image, que tipo apesar de dar a ideia de imagens, image -> 1 imagem (mas isso é bem improvável). Aliás, caso isso for o ocorrido possívelmente vai acontecer algum erro no console mesmo avisando tipo "Cara a imagem que você enviou pra mim é insegura, então boa sorte"
2 - Angular Buildado, quando você builda o angular ele junta tudo em uma pasta, é como se isso daqui:
slac/
| src/
| | app/
| | | meu-componente.ts
| | outras-coisas.../
| assets/
| blah-blah-blah

Virasse isso daqui depois de buildado:
slac/
| main.js
| assets/

então caso você estiver hospedando o angular ou testando ele depois de buildar com o ng build, existe a possíbilidade de tú estiver tomando essa daí de revesgueio. É bom tentar colocar isso daqui no caminho da pasta /assets/sua-pasta-ou-imagem, pq ele detecta automaticamente onde fica o caminho da pasta assets ou também tem o ./assets.
3 - Referência do builder do angular. Que o angular é buildado definitivamente não é novidade, mas na hora do build ele pode estar referenciando errado sua pasta de assets, você pode ver onde ele está referenciando no arquivo angular.json

4 - Por ultimo o mais provável é que o seu código funcione se você colocar algo assim no src="assets/seu-caminho.blahblahblah" isso funcionaria justamente por causa do tópico anterior aí da referência do assets do próprio angular.
Talvez alguma baboseira q eu falei aí possa te ajudar Gustavo ;)
( In English )
1 - Angular had trouble with security, so angular is a framework that takes its security very seriously, sometimes if you put some file that you want to show in your application outside the assets folder, it has a probability that angualar will throw a error claiming that the file is not secure. So there's a possibility that angular is giving you trouble because of the folder's name, But theres a small chance that is the true nature of the error. (A VERY VERY SMALL CHANCE)
2 - If you're testing or trying your app after building, it should throw you a error specifying that the path "../../../something" does noth exist becaus of angular's post building folders state. Before building it should look something like this:
slac/
| src/
| | app/
| | | meu-componente.ts
| | outras-coisas.../
| assets/
| blah-blah-blah

after building:
slac/
| main.js
| assets/

so in this case you sould put inside the img's source something like: "assets/yourfile.blahblah" or "./assets/yourfile.blahblah" this should work.
3 - Wrong angular builder reference. Angular has its own path to identify the assets folder, this reference is located at angular.json here:

if this path is wrong you may have trouble, but its very uncommon to have a error inside angular.json
4 - Finally, try setting inside the src, something like the path pre-setted in angular.json, (the path shown in the third topic). It should work, it will become something like this: src="assets/your-path.blahblahblah".
if none of those four answers solved your problem, congratulations you found some miracle or an hidden angular bug
